# How to read the values from one method in another method

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

The following is the code which i am using,

```
- (void) readDataFromDatabase{

    sqlite3 *database;
    persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from sdata";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                pID = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
                pName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                pAdd = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                pPh = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 3);
                pCp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
                pLat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                pLong = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];

                Person *temp = [[Person alloc]initWithID:pID name:pName address:pAdd phone:pPh contactperson:pCp fLat:pLat fLong:pLong];


                [persons addObject:temp];
                NSLog(@"Inside Persons : %@",persons);
                [temp release];

            }

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
For the NSLog in  NSLog(@"Inside Persons : %@",persons);i get the output as Inside Persons : ("<Person: 0x4c26ae0>"

- (void)startTest
{

    for(int j=0;j<[persons count];j++){

        Person *arr = [persons objectAtIndex:j];


        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",arr.fLat] ;
        NSLog(@" data in array : %@", s);
    }


#define COORDS_COUNT 1
#define RADIUS       100.0f

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[COORDS_COUNT] = {
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([arr.fLat floatValue], [arr.fLong floatValue ]),


    };

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue], [longt floatValue]); 
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:RADIUS identifier:@"Banashankari"];



    for (int i = 0; i < COORDS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = coords[i];

        NSString *coordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",coord.latitude, coord.longitude];
        [dataArray addObject:coordString];

        if ([region containsCoordinate:coord])
        {
            NSLog(@"location %f, %f is within %.0f meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);
            [resultArray addObject:coordString];
            NSLog(@"data in resultArray %@",resultArray);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"location %f, %f is not within %.0f meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);    

        }
    }
}
```

For the NSLog(@" data in array : %@", s); i am getting the output as data in array : 0.000000, but the expected value is 12.920684, 77.560033.
How to get the expected value in startTest Method, where i am doing the mistake.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @property(non atomic,retain) for the `nsmutablearray` persons? Also try to check if the value if fetched in the array. Use retain after the array is filled with values.

Comment: I have used the @property(nonatomic,retain) for the NSMutablearray persons.

Comment: and how about retaining the mutable array after                 [persons addObject:temp];   Also try to check if the value if fetched in the array??

Comment: I also tried retaining the mutable array after [persons addObject:temp]; but not getting the value

Comment: what is the output of persons. Use NSLog and check.

Comment: the persons output is Inside Persons : ("<Person: 0x4c20980>").

Comment: r u sure u r getting values for temp and also pID,pname and all?

Comment: ya I am sure i am getting the values for temp and also for pID,pname.

Comment: how about         Person *arr = [persons objectAtIndex:j];?? what is fLat's datatype? use nslof after 'arr'

Comment: fLat's datatype is NSString.for arr it is displaying 0.00000 in NSLog

Comment: obvious it is as u r using %f instead of %@

Comment: I got it now i changed it to %@ and getting the value.Thanks a lot. One more doubt i have i am getting only the last value. but i want all the values.

Comment: that is because you are using slog for nsstring and not an array.. :)

Comment: when i put it to arr, i get the following data in array : <Person: 0x4c57df0>

Comment: ya i am doing NSLog(@" data in array : %@", arr); is it correct or wrong way.

Comment: use [retain arr] after         Person *arr = [persons objectAtIndex:j]; also arr is locally defined, define it outside for loop. then come outside for loop and then call the NSLog method.

Comment: now i am getting it, i just changed some lines, where the Person *temp = [[Person alloc]initWithID:pID name:pName address:pAdd phone:pPh contactperson:pCp fLat:pLat fLong:pLong];


                [persons addObject:temp];
                NSLog(@"Inside Persons : %@",persons);
                [temp release];
i moved it back to while. till now i had kept outside the while loop in readDataFromDatabase.

Comment: so should i assume that u have got the solution?

Comment: sorry for late response. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: my pleasure...how about accepting the answer,if was helpful..??

Comment: I have got new problem in my project, I have updated the code, in the startTest method there is a if-else condition where i check where the latitude and longitude are within 100 metres or not, In the log it is showing correctly like which are in within 100 meters and which are not within 100 meters. But in my table view i am getting all the latitude and longitude, but i need to show only the those latitude and longitude which comes within 100 meters

Comment: start a new post. As it's quite a lengthy conversation.